# Call to undefined function error when connecting to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I'm just starting to learn how to create dynamic PHP sites and want to figure out how to connect to a MySQL database. I currently have a domain and hosting which runs PHP version 5.4.37 and MySQL 6.5.23. 
I've looked at different tutorials which all specify the following code to connect to a database:

```
<?php
$username="myusername";
$password="mypassword";

$database="overeasy_runner";

$link = mysql_connect("mel-s22e",$username,

$password) or die(mysql_error());
echo "connected";
?>
```

I currently get this error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /home/overeasy/public_html/testing.php on line 8

I'm not sure if it is because of hostname, username etc settings or something wrong with my code. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your host name?

Comment: hostname has nothing to do with it. the php hasn't been compiled with support for mysql_*. try pdo? what is the output of `phpinfo()` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what pdo is. What info would you like from the output?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mysqli. Here is an example that will help you.

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'database');
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
?>
```

Comment: I'm actually also unsure if I should be using the username and passwords for my host or for the mysql database I want to connect to

Comment: you need to use the database details. The password and user name of the database.

Comment: thanks. mysqli worked - can you tell me why?
also - i logged in with host details rather than the database details and that worked...

Answer (score 0):

use this.

```
<?php
 $host = "localhost";
 $db_name = "overeasy_runner";
 $user = "root";
 $password = "";

 $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or die("connection error");

 mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("could't connect to database");
 ?>
```